# Error: Can't resolve all parameters for XXX: (?). Angular 4.0.2

Tags: angular, typescript, systemjs

I've seen this error in many previous SO question, but none of them seems related with this case, just after an upgrade to the latest version 4.0.2. It's not a circular DI and doesn't seem related with polifills.

I'm using `SystemJS` and `jspm` (not webpack), maybe `jspm` is related with the issue but I can't figure out how.

The app entry point is main.ts:

```
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone'; 
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule2 } from './app/app.module2';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule2);
```

My module, `app.module2.ts`, is quite simple:

```
import { NgModule, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule, Http } from '@angular/http';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  template: `<h2>Hola</h2>`    
})
export class HomeComponent {
  constructor(private http : Http) {
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
   BrowserModule, HttpModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    HomeComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [ HomeComponent ],
  entryComponents: [  ],
  providers: [
  ]
})
export class AppModule2 { }
```

When I launch the app (using Chrome 57) the error is:

```
Error: Can't resolve all parameters for HomeComponent: (?).
  Evaluating http://localhost:3000/src/main.ts
  Loading myapp
    at syntaxError (http://localhost:3000/jspm_packages/npm/@angular/compiler@4.0.2/bundles/compiler.umd.js:1513:34) [<root>]
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (http://localhost:3000/jspm_packages/npm/@angular/compiler@4.0.2/bundles/compiler.umd.js:14363:35) [<root>]
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (http://localhost:3000/jspm_packages/npm/@angular/compiler@4.0.2/bundles/compiler.umd.js:14231:26) [<root>]
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNonNormalizedDirectiveMetadata (http://localhost:3000/jspm_packages/npm/@angular/compiler@4.0.2/bundles/compiler.umd.js:13840:24) [<root>]
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getEntryComponentMetadata (http://localhost:3000/jspm_packages/npm/@angular/compiler@4.0.2/bundles/compiler.umd.js:14484:45) [<root>]
    at eval (http://localhost:3000/jspm_packages/npm/@angular/compiler@4.0.2/bundles/compiler.umd.js:14067:108) [<root>]
    at Array.map (native) [<root>]
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (http://localhost:3000/jspm_packages/npm/@angular/compiler@4.0.2/bundles/compiler.umd.js:14067:73) [<root>]
    at JitCompiler._loadModules (http://localhost:3000/jspm_packages/npm/@angular/compiler@4.0.2/bundles/compiler.umd.js:25144:64) [<root>]
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (http://localhost:3000/jspm_packages/npm/@angular/compiler@4.0.2/bundles/compiler.umd.js:25103:52) [<root>]
    at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (http://localhost:3000/jspm_packages/npm/@angular/compiler@4.0.2/bundles/compiler.umd.js:25065:21) [<root>]
    at PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleWithZone (http://localhost:3000/jspm_packages/npm/@angular/core@4.0.2/bundles/core.umd.js:4793:25) [<root>]
    at PlatformRef_.bootstrapModule (http://localhost:3000/jspm_packages/npm/@angular/core@4.0.2/bundles/core.umd.js:4779:21) [<root>]
    at Object.execute (http://localhost:3000/src/main.ts!transpiled:19:65) [<root>]
```

If I remove the injection of `Http` in `HomeComponent` the app load successfully.

My tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  }
}
```

Comment: It is because you are missing the @Injectable() decorator? Source: https://gist.github.com/gsans/d020de5f0fbe56a22c824e1158ba7ec8#file-mycomponent-ts

Comment: @floor The problem is with an angular service, where should I add `@Injectable()` in this code ?

Comment: try: import { CommonModule, Injectable } from '@angular/common'; and drop @Injectable() above your home component export.

Comment: No, that's not the problem, `@Injectable()` is necessary for angular Services, not Components, the `@Component` It should be enough to detect and use DI. About Services in Angular tutorial: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html

Comment: Hmm.. maybe try creating an injectable service that uses http. Maybe http can't be used directly in a component? Or trying specifying providers for your component: providers: [http] ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many tests, the problem is not in the angular code but in the loading system based on systemjs and the default config provided by jspm that load the files in typescript (.ts) and the browser compiles to js on the fly. Maybe is a problem with the transpiler `plugin-typescript`.

There are something wrong in the process, I wouldn't know to say what is exactly, anyway, if we configure `systemjs` to load the modules directly in js then the problem disappears.

I've remove all the references to typescript in the module formats, so from the original file, the config:

```
transpiler: "plugin-typescript",
packages: {
    "main": {
      "main": "main.ts",
      "format": "esm",
      "defaultExtension": "ts",
      "meta": {
        "*.ts": {
          "loader": "plugin-typescript"
        }
      }
    }
},
```

It becomes in:

```
transpiler: false,
packages: {
    'app': {
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    },
    'main': {
      main: 'main.js',
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    }
},
map: {
    'main': 'src',
    'app': 'src/app'
}
```

Now the app loads without problem.

I'm using [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) to program the app, so when I edit a .ts file a .js and a .map file are generated automatically, the transpiling process is done in dev-time, besides, using Chrome, I can debug using the original .ts files so I think I don't lose anything with this approach.

If anyone has a better approach, just tell me.